# How do I pass python variables to subprocess call to sed?

Tags: python, bash, sed

I'm trying to send a call to sed but it seems like it is not processing the variables it looks correct when I print it but it not correct in the call

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
import json
from pprint import pprint
from subprocess import call


with open('admin_list.json') as data_file:    
    admins = json.load(data_file)

#pprint(data[0]["key"])
for admin in admins:
    #print(admin["name"])
    #print (" sudo sed, 1 a  ${"+admin['key']+"} /home/"+admin['name']+"/.ssh/authorized_keys")
    call(["sudo sed", "1 a  ${"+admin['key']+"} /home/"+admin['name']+"/.ssh/authorized_keys"])
```

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

I've updated my code I do not get errors but the file still is not updated

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
import json
import os
from pprint import pprint
from subprocess import call


with open('admin_list.json') as data_file:    
    admins = json.load(data_file)

#pprint(data[0]["key"])
for admin in admins:

    call(["sudo","sed", "1 a "+admin['key']+"","/home/"+admin['name']+"/.ssh/authorized_keys"])
    call(['cat','/home/'+admin["name"]+'/.ssh/authorized_keys'])
```

Comment: Using `sudo` to modify other people's `ssh` configuration sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: So what is the best practice for adding new admins to a server, I'm trying to automate the setup of new servers and automatically add the public key for admins to their authorized keys after the user is created

Comment: I'd use a tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com) or something else that's purpose-built for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split your arguments properly else spaces will be interpreted literally

Here you have 4 arguments:

- sudo
- sed
- argument of sed
- file to parse as admin

And don't rely on env. variables, evaluate them beforehand (else you'll need `shell=True`)

so pass a 4-item list to `call`

```
call(["sudo","sed", "1 a  "+os.getenv(admin['key']),"/home/"+admin['name']+"/.ssh/authorized_keys"])
```

note that to modify your file in-place you need to add `-i` option to `sed`:

```
call(["sudo","sed", "-i", "1 a  "+os.getenv(admin['key']),"/home/"+admin['name']+"/.ssh/authorized_keys"])
```

Comment: Thanks I was converting this from a shell script to a python script so I could read in the admin list from a json file and have a list of admins with there public key to add to their authorized_keys file

Comment: What is os.getenv doing here ?

Comment: I get a TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: I updated it to use 4 list items "call(["sudo","sed", "1 a  ${"+admin['key']+"}","/home/"+admin['name']+"/.ssh/authorized_keys"])" Do noot get any errors but file is not updated

Comment: getenv is used to evaluate your env. variable. Else it's not evaluated. And the file isn't updated, because, well, you didn't use `-i` option of `sed` (how are we supposed to know you want to update the file?)

Comment: when I try with the os.getenv like the example you provided I get an error ": cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"

Comment: man page shows -a and -i as the same thing this is what I used in my bash file        sudo sed "1 a  ${KEY}" /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: you're mixing up `i` sed command with `-i` _inplace_ command line _option_